# Is there a way to ignore commas inside of quotation marks in python?

Tags: python, regex, split

I am parsing (splitting) many lines to lists, separating values by commas. But I am encountering a problem when my lines contain strings with commas inside. For example:

Instead of parsing the line `"21467,dog,888,"apples,oranges,melons",777"`
to the values:

- 21467
- dog
- 888
- apples,oranges,melons
- 777

The parsed list contains:

- 21467
- dog
- 888
- apples
- oranges
- melons
- 777

My current code is using split function:

```
for line in s:
    parsed_line = line.split(",")
```

From what I've checked in there is no way to overcome this problem simply by using the split function, I suspect I'm going to need to use regex.

Any ideas or examples on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @azro He meant "instead of doing <what I wanted>, it actually does <this>.

Comment: The string format is borked. Where does it come from?

Comment: Does the sample string really have double quotes at the beginning and end?

Comment: Or indeed, you've just added the outer quotes and you should instead be using a general CSV parser, like the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

Comment: You don't need to implement regex. Seems like you're dealing with CSV (comma separate values) format, where the use of double quotes to "escape" splits is a standard. As @roganjosh suggested, the python csv module and specifically its `reader` object will handle this easily.

Comment: I totally agree with @roganjosh and @kishkash: Use a CSV parser and don't use a regex to solve it. You'll have to handle special cases such as spaces or tabs around the commas or some quotes inside the string values, typically with an example like this: `21467,  dog, 888, "apples, ""fabulous"" oranges & melons", 777`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting, you can find all matches using the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/CbzMqE/1), `"[^"]*"|[^,]+`.

```
import re

line = '21467,dog,888,"apples,oranges,melons",777'
matches = re.findall('"[^"]*"|[^,]+', line)
for s in matches:
    print(s)
```

**Output**:

```
21467
dog
888
"apples,oranges,melons"
777
```

**Explanation of the regex**:

- `"[^"]*"`: Anything enclosed by double quotes
- `|`: OR
- `[^,]+`: Any character, one or more times, other than `,`

Comment: What happens if the string contains some quotes?, typically something like `21467, dog, 888, "apples, ""fabulous"" oranges, melons", 777`. Spaces around the commas should also be handled. This is why I wouldn't try to solve it with a regex but use a CSV parser which will probably be more bullet proof.

Comment: @PatrickJanser - I agree with you that using a CSV parser will probably be more bulletproof solution.

Comment: I love using regular expressions and it's fun to write them and solve a problem quickly! But sometimes I have to admit that other tools are especially made for that and that we should stick to them if we don't want to have some bugs that often appear randomly later when the input suddenly has something we didn't think about.

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird for the valuable suggestion as usual. I've updated the answer accordingly.